# WooCommerce Rest API error when use POST and GET

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

in there i try to use api `customers` from woocommerce, when i try to use it i always get response :
url : `http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/customers`

```
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}


{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
  "message": "Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

and sometime :

and for create :

```
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_create",
  "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

what should i do ?

i already add the key :

[image: here]

or i only can have 1 key ? :
[image: here]

or i need to update one of the script ?

hope, someone can help me to resolve my problem

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this exact issue, however I have good and bad news from my experience, sometimes the API would shut me out when I had made literally no changes, sometimes rebooting the NGINX server would fix this.

At the moment my connection with postman and OAuth 1.0 yields the following;

```
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

With that our of the way:

1. Ensure the 'Type' is set to OAuth 1.0 in postman.
2. Ensure your URL is correct, (http, or https).

As I said above, I never managed to keep mine stable, and it would drop out without changing a single thing.

How I solved this was by using 'Basic Auth', Username `your_ck`, password `your_cs`. I believe that you need to be using SSL to use Basic Auth but setting up SSL isn't a big deal so it was definitely worth it.

If you do find out why OAuth 1.0 is failing i'd love to hear.

EDIT: There are many examples of people with this issue [example with image](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/11714) may help you. But it seems most people settle for Basic Auth.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue, i tried in Postman, PHP, NodeJs everthing, almost spend 2 days but no output, finally started getting response after putting a slash at the end of the URL,

I mean,

Initially i was using https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=ck_XXXX&consumer_secret=cs_XXXX
but change it to like this https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?consumer_key=ck_XXXX&consumer_secret=cs_XXXX (Just put a slash before question mark in the start of query string).

In Postman even without set any Authorization settings(Type = No Auth), i started getting responses.

It may be somehow related to my .htaccess, but i feel it would good if i post this solution also here.

Comment: how do i work for Localhost ? @josmy Jose

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given Read/Write Access to the user and also check your .htaccess file in the root directory. Try using this code in .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```